# Automating Inline::Java Installation on Linux (Centos/Redhat)

Tags: java, linux, perl, installation, inline

I'm maintaining a perl script which runs an automated install of our base server software.  One of the new requirements is to install the Inline::Java module.

Our usual strategy of installing using Yum seems to fall down as there's no Inline::Java available in yum. I can't find an RPM release for it so can't install as an RPM.  The only options seem to be installing through CPAN or shipping the tar and having a step which identifies the SDK location and runs 'perl Makefile.PL J2SDK=; make; make install'.

Instinctually I think that's a little shaky for an automated install, I've had problems with CPAN installs failing in the past and I don't really want to have to make on a live server, but I can't think of a better option.

The other option I considered was just shipping the .pm file, placing it in a user defined directory and using 'use lib' to define that as a location but due to the way Inline::Java works I don't think this is possible, it needs the location of the InlineJavaServer and such too.

Does anyone have a better solution or an opinion on which of the ones proposed above is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inline::Java` will look for `InlineJavaServer.jar` and the other files it needs in the same location as the `Inline/Java.pm` file. Copying the whole distribution from the install directory on one machine and copying it to another machine (with the same architecture) isn't as crazy as it sounds. If you only have a few different systems (not all linux, 32 bit vs 64 bit, perl 5.6 vs perl 5.10, etc.), it is tractable to make a separate package for each system.

There is some install-time configuration in `Inline::Java`, including specifying the default Java installation to use. But this (and other default configurations) can always be overridden with environment variables like `PERL_INLINE_JAVA_J2SDK` (see the [Inline::Java perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::Java) for the complete list). You could package `Inline::Java` with your own custom module, say,
`MyCompany::InlineJavaConfig`, that can set the appropriate environment variables before the `Inline::Java` module gets loaded in each script.

There's some other install-time configuration like whether to configure JNI and other native support. It might be a little dicier to copy the files that support these features from one machine to another. But I can't think of any reason off-hand that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I someone missed that environment variable.  This solution has worked for me, with minimal disruption.

Answer (score 3):

You could [build your own](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Perl) `perl-Inline-Java` package and put it in a private yum repository, or even contribute it to Fedora/EPEL.

Comment: This is probably the better answer but I ran into some problems creating the RPM and as I'm on a tight timescale I've taken the easy option and gone with the copying directory strategy.

I tried using cpan2rpm to create the RPM. The problems I ran into were to do with the dynamic nature of the Inline::Java packaging, it seemed to have an dependency on Inline::Java->find_default_j2sdk (which finds a file generated at build time) that I couldn't override.

It's likely my failing though, I'm far from an RPM expert.  I might try again when I have some spare time.